# How to get day-month in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a data table in which my Date column is in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`. How can i change it to `DD-MM` only? For example, 12-03-2015 would be 12-03. I only find `DATEPART()` which does not help me.

Comment: Why doesn't that help you? You can query using DATEPART to get the day and month, and ignore the year.  Alternatively, you could create a custom data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateCol, 105), 1, 5)
```

Sample Data:

```
;WITH CTE(DateCol) AS(
    SELECT CAST('20150312' AS DATE) UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('20150123' AS DATE) UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('20150228' AS DATE) UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('20151011' AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateCol, 105), 1, 5) 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the 5 first characters with convert:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), getdate(), 105)
```